# Selecting products for product comparison: Mobile UX?

Tags: e-commerce

On desktop we have something similar to this

[image]

source: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/comparison-tables/

As you click the "+" it adds items to your "items to compare" list that is fixed to the bottom of the screen.

I like this UX on desktop, but how can we translate it to mobile?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from Walgreens. You could expand this approach and offer an expandable drawer for users to see the items they have currently added to the comparison list, before opening the comparison page.

An additional consideration for mobile is the treatment of the comparison table in limited screen real estate. There are a few articles regarding this, [here is one](https://medium.com/appnroll-publication/5-practical-solutions-to-make-responsive-data-tables-ff031c48b122).

[image]